# How to run multiple external commands in the background in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, unix, process, multitasking

Given this Unix shell script:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 2 &
sleep 5 &
sleep 1 &
wait
```

time ./test.sh

```
real 0m5.008s
user 0m0.040s
sys  0m0.000s
```

How would you accomplish the same thing in Ruby on a Unix machine?

*The sleep commands are just an example, just assume that they are long running external commands instead.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from [`Process#waitall`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001291) documentation:

```
fork { sleep 0.2; exit 2 }   #=> 27432
fork { sleep 0.1; exit 1 }   #=> 27433
fork {            exit 0 }   #=> 27434
p Process.waitall
```

Of course, instead of using Ruby's `sleep`, you can call whichever external command using [`Kernel#system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441), or [backtick operator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001408).

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question (just found out about this):

```
​#!/usr/bin/ruby

spawn 'sleep 2'
spawn 'sleep 5'
spawn 'sleep 1'

Process.waitall
```

On ruby 1.8 you need to install the sfl gem and also require this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sfl'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
pids = []
pids << Kernel.fork { `sleep 2` }
pids << Kernel.fork { `sleep 5` }
pids << Kernel.fork { `sleep 1` }
pids.each { |pid| Process.wait(pid) }
```