# How to feed data over STDIN to multiple external commands in ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, process, stdin

This question is a bit like my previous (answered) question:

[How to run multiple external commands in the background in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689592/how-to-run-multiple-external-commands-in-the-background-in-ruby)

But, in this case I am looking for a way to feed ruby strings over STDIN to external processes, something like this (the code below is not valid but illustrates my goal):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

str1 = 'In reality a relatively large string.....'
str2 = 'Another large string'
str3 = 'etc..'

spawn 'some_command.sh', :stdin => str1
spawn 'some_command.sh', :stdin => str2
spawn 'some_command.sh', :stdin => str3

Process.waitall
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
data = [str1, str2, str3]

data.each do |input|
  fork do
    IO.popen(COMMAND, 'r+'){|n| n.print input}
  end
end

Process.waitall
```

Comment: Aren't processes more efficient on Unix? Processes are distributed among the available CPUs/cores.

Comment: you are already starting a new process with popen (it creates a process and pipe to communicate with it). So with fork you are creating two processes for each command.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to split the output from one app to two others and couldn't get `tee` to work. I resorted to this ruby script.

```
alpha = IO.popen( "some shell command" , 'r+' ) 
bravo = IO.popen( "other command" , 'r+' ) 

ARGF.each_line do |line| 
  alpha << line
  bravo << line 
end
```